# Sending a stream of images from RPI pi camera to my PC for image recognition (yolov5)

Tags: picamera

I am using a RPI Pi camera for my image recognition project. For my project, I need to send a stream of images of a library from RPI pi camera to a PC, and perform image recognition on the PC to deduce whether the seats in the library are occupied or vacant, and send the prediction results to another app/website.

However, I am not experienced with RPI or its hardware.

How to stream camera images from RPI to PC so that I can perform OpenCV and yolov5 on the images on the PC?

Comment: your question is not really Raspberry Pi specific ... research in the Linux realm

Comment: Oh I’m not very sure.. what I need to do is stream images in maybe 5fps or so from my rpi Camera (v2) of my rpi to my PC/laptop, such that I can access these frames in opencv for image processing and recognition (using yolov5s). I thought it’d be specific to rpi since I need to use picamera library or such?

Comment: `libcamera` library should allow you work with camera interface and perform I/O on images from the camera (still or video). Once you get that, it's a matter of figuring out how you want to stream the images. `libcamera` offers network streaming over `UTP`, `TCP` or `RSTP` out of the box. see https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#network-streaming. If the native streaming capability is not good enough you can write your own streaming layer or use `HLS` or `webRTC` or `DASH` or `SRT` etc to stream camera feed over the network